# Viewstate and dynamically added rows

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I'm having some trouble with `ViewState`, perhaps I don't understand how it works.

I have a table and add rows to it dynamically, but when I try to add the rows to the `ViewState`, the rows are not displayed (added?) in the table.

```
private void randomPageMethod()
{


     ...get data & generate row...
     ViewState.Add(tr.ID, tr);
     tableLSHTime.Rows.AddAt(1, tr);
}
```

If I remove the `ViewState.Add(tr.ID, tr)` line, the rows are added, but `ofc` not preserved.

I would like to use `Page_Load` like this (when I use `ViewState`):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      
      ...code code...
      if (IsPostBack)
      {
            foreach (TableRow tr in ViewState)
            {
                tableLSHTime.Rows.Add(tr);
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Any reason not to use the build in data controls like GridView or ListView?

Comment: No reason, its just bugging me like crazy. If I use Session instead of ViewState everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding rows directly to viewstate, use a datatable and add rows to it, and add the datatable to viewstate. If can be retrieved and looped through inside page_load handler.